# $_GET all values from single php variable and convert to 1,2,3

Tags: php, arrays, variables, explode, implode

I have a single variable with multiple values eg: domain.com/index.php?cat=1&cat=2&cat=3

When I use $_GET[cat] it will only get the last value '3'

How do I get all the values?  Is it possible to then convert this result into a string:

eg: 1,2,3

Thanks

Comment: You should name the variable `cat[]`. It will cause PHP to generate an array with all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use PHP array syntax to accomplish this:

```
domain.com/index.php?cat[]=1&cat[]=2&cat[]=3
```

Then in PHP:

```
$cats = implode(',', $_GET['cat']);
echo $cats; // 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you have to add brackets to make your variable an array

```
domain.com/index.php?cat[]=1&cat[]=2&cat[]=3
```

Then in PHP

```
echo $_GET['cat'][0]; // Outputs 1
```